# Finding the maximum and minimum values of $f(x)=a^x+a^{1/x}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f(x)=a^x+a^{1/x}\ (x\gt 0)$ where $a\in\mathbb R$ is a constant.

> **Question 1** : What is the **maximum** value of $f(x)$ for $0\lt a\lt 1$?
>
> **Question 2** : What is the **minimum** value of $f(x)$ for $a\gt 1$?

The followings may be true:

Conjecture 1 : For $a=1/2$, the maximum value of $f(x)$ is $f(1)=1$.

Conjecture 2 : For $0\lt a\lt 1, a\not =1/2$, $f(x)$ does not have the maximum value.

Conjecture 3 : For $a\gt 1$, the minimum value of $f(x)$ is $f(1)=2a$.

I'm afraid that these may be very easy questions, but to be honest I don't have any good idea to solve them. Can anyone help?

**Edit 1** : Question 2 has already been solved by Barry Cipra. (Conjecture 3 is true) However, Question 1 has not been solved yet.

**Edit 2** : I've just been able to prove that the conjecture 1 is true. Also, I found that the conjecture 2 is not true, but I'm not able to answer the question 1 in general.

Comment: No $a>0{}$ too?

Comment: For both questions, the maxima and minima are achieved when $ x = \frac{1}{x} $. Thus, for $x=1$, you have $f(x) = 2a$.

Comment: is a any real number or can it only be an integer?

Comment: @GitGud: I wrote $a\gt 0$ in the question.

Comment: @hjpotter92: Could you please explain why you can say so? It is not obvious to me.

Comment: @VarunIyer: I wrote $a\in\mathbb R$ in the question.

Comment: @mathlove I see that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you're solving questions like these, it is always best to use calculus.

So we have a function where $$f(x) = a^x + a^{1/x}$$

Taking the derivative: $$f'(x)= a^x\ln a - \frac{a^{1/x}\ln a}{x^2}$$

Now we set the equation equal to 0 find the value(s) of x that make it maximum or minimum.

$$a^x\ln a - \frac{a^{1/x}\ln a}{x^2} = 0$$
$\ln a$ is always, greater than $0$, so

$$a^x-\frac{a^{1/x}}{x^2} = 0$$

Therefore, when $x = -1, 1$, $f'(x) = 0$ **EDIT:** $x > 0$, so we can only use $x = 1$

When $a > 1$

Our minimum value occurs at $x = 1$, because from $(0, 1)$, $f'(x) < 0$, and from $(1, \infty)$, $f'(x) > 0$, using [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20f%28x%29%3D%202%5Ex%5Cln%202%20-%20%5Cfrac%7B2%5E%7B1%2Fx%7D%5Cln%202%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D%20) graph (I choose an arbitrary a in order to graph it).

$$f(1)= a^{1} + a^{1} = 2a$$

When $a = 1/2$

We go back to our $f'(x)$ equation, and we substitute $a = 1/2$ We get $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x} - \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/x}}{x^2}$$ Looking at [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7Bx%7D%20-%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7B1%2Fx%7D%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D), we see that the max. value occurs at $x = 0.215106, 4.64886$, and the min. value occurs at $x = 1$.

When $0 < a < 1$, $a \not= 1/2$

You can graph the function for an arbitrary $a$, and you'll see that the function has a max value at $x = 1$

Comment: I have a question. We can see that if $x= 1$, then $f'(x)=0.$ However, can we say $f'(x)=0$ only when $x= 1$? Or we don't need to think about the other solutions of $f'(x)=0$? If so, why?

Comment: actually, I messed up, $f'(x)$  doesn't equal 0 when $x = -1.$ I will change. So sorry

Comment: I don't think you answered the question in my comment...

Comment: He cannot because generally there are more zeroes of the derivative. Example: For $a=4/10$ you have the following zeroes $x_1= 0.48164\dots, \; x_2 = 1, \; x_3=1/x_1=2.07623\dots$ for $f'(x)$.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please read it.

Comment: @VarunIyer: First, the domain of $f(x)$ is $x\gt 0$. So, how about the case when $x\gt 1$?

Comment: @mathlove My answer is updated for every conjecture you stated.

Comment: @VarunIyer: Well, so you want to say, 'according to this graph'... This is not what I want. (Actually my three conjectures come from the same way you did) I think you don't prove that my three conjectures are true.

Comment: @VarunIyer: For example, we know that the maximum value of $f(x)$ would be $f(1)=1$ for $a=1/2$ using wolfram alpha. Then, how can we prove it without using such tools. This is my question.

Answer (score 6):

Conjecture 3 can be handled with the [arithmetic-geometric mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), in the form $u+v\ge2\sqrt{uv}$:  If $a\gt1$, then

$$a^x+a^{1/x}\ge2\sqrt{a^xa^{1/x}}=2\sqrt{a^{x+1/x}}\ge2\sqrt{a^{2\sqrt{x\cdot1/x}}}=2\sqrt{a^2}=2a$$

with equality when $x=1$.  (Note, the assumption $a\gt1$ is crucial when replacing the exponent $x+1/x$ with the smaller exponent $2\sqrt{x\cdot1/x}$.  If $a$ were smaller than $1$, the inequality would point in the "wrong" direction.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this very strict proof.

Answer (score 2):

I've just been able to prove that **the conjecture 1 is true** (Conjecture 1 : For $a=1/2$, the maximum value of $f(x)=a^x+a^{1/x}$ is $f(1)=1$.
). Also, I found that the conjecture 2 is not true, but I'm not able to answer the question 1 in general.

In the following, I'm going to prove that the maximum value of $f(x)=a^x+a^{1/x}$ is $f(1)=1$ for $a=1/2$.

Since setting $x=1/t$ in $a^x+a^{1/x}$ gives us $a^{1/t}+a^t$, we can see that it is sufficient to prove that the maximum value of $f(x)\ (0\lt x\le 1)$ is $1$.

Since $f(x)\lt 1\iff (1-2^{-x})\cdot 2^{1/x}\gt 1$, I'm going to prove that $$g(x)=(1-2^{-x})\cdot 2^{1/x}\gt 1\ (0\lt x\lt 1).$$

We get $$g'(x)=\log2\cdot 2^{1/x}\cdot \frac{(x^2+1)\cdot 2^{-x}-1}{x^2}.$$

In the following, I'm going to prove that $h(x)=(x^2+1)\cdot 2^{-x}-1\lt 0$.

The tangent line of $y=2^x$ at $(0,1)$ is $y=(\log2)x+1$ and at $(1,2)$ is $y=(2\log2)(x-1)+2.$ Since the intersection point of these lines is $(2-1/\log2,2\log2)$, let 
$$h(x)=(\log2)x+1\ \ (0\lt x\lt 2-1/\log2), (2\log2)(x-1)+2\ \ (2-1/\log2\le x\lt 1).$$

Then, since $y=2^x$ is convex downward, we get $2^x\gt h(x).$ Also, since we can see $$(2-1/\log2)^2+1\lt 2\log 2\iff (\log4-1)(1-\log2)^2\gt 0,$$
we can get $h(2-1/\log 2)\gt x^2+1$. Hence, since $y=x^2+1$ is convex downward, we get $h(x)\gt x^2+1.$

Hence, since we get $2^x\gt x^2+1$, we get $(x^2+1)\cdot 2^{-x}-1\lt 0$. Hence, since we get $g'(x)\lt 0$ and $g(1)=1$, we get $g(x)\gt 1$ for $0\lt x\lt 1.$ **Q.E.D.**

Comment: The maximum is $f(1)=2a$ for all $a \in [1/2, 1)$, your approach inspired me here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4598625/42969