# No clear analytic method to prove unique maximum? ($2^{-x}+2^{-1/x}$)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, fixed-point-theorems

Prove that $f(x) = 2^{-x}+2^{-1/x}$ has the *unique* local maximum $(1,1)$ for $x>0$. Do not use computer software.

Proving that $(1,1)$ is a maximum is easy, but I'm having trouble with the uniqueness part. The first derivative has an unclear number of zeroes because of its mixed logarithmic/polynomial form.

I've reduced it to showing that $x = 2^{(x-1/x)/2}$ has a unique fixed point on $(0,1)$, but this has proved difficult as well. None of the typical unique fixed point theorems seem to apply.

I'm sure that certain iterative methods could show uniqueness, but I'm not sure how to use these without resorting to software and approximations.

Comment: This is the same as conjecture 1 in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858835/finding-the-maximum-and-minimum-values-of-fx-axa1-x) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/859903/78967) answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the maximum and minimum values of $f(x)=a^x+a^{1/x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858835/finding-the-maximum-and-minimum-values-of-fx-axa1-x)

Comment: Here is an answer:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1598849p9938551

Answer (score 1):

Not as pleasing as the AM-GM inequality, but since $f$ and its derivatives are all continuous except the discontinuity at $x=0$:

1. you can differentiate $f$, then analytically show $f'$ is zero at x=1, as well as somewhere around 0.2 (here using the intermediate value theorem].
2. obtain $f''$ and show it is positive at $x\approx 0.2$ and negative at $x=1.$
3. conclude $x=1$ is a unique local maximum of this function