# Prove that $2^a+2^{1\over a} \le 1$ for $a<0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponentiation, real-numbers, maxima-minima

> **QUESTION:**
>   Prove that if $a<0$, then $2^a+2^{1\over a} \le 1$.

**How I started it**:
So, if a<0, then there exists a number $u>0$ satisfying $a=-u$.
We have $2^{-u} + 2^{-1\over u} \le 1$ or by exponent rules
$1\over 2^u$$+$$1\over 2^{1\over u}$$\le 1$ but I got stuck here. Any help would be appreciated. Also, I need an algebraic non-calculus solution.

Comment: What happens if you multiply both sides by $2^u$?

Comment: You get $1 + {2^u\over 2^{1\over u}} \le 2^u$ or
$1 \le 2^u - 2^{u - {1\over u}}$ which to me seems even more complicated

Comment: Let's set $2^u=y, 2^{1\over u}=z$. We have ${1\over y} + {1\over z} \le 1$; 
${y+z\over yz} \le 1$; $y+z \le yz$; $0 \le yz-y-z$; $1 \le yz-y-z+1$; 
$1 \le (y-1)(z-1)$. So the expression you wrote should be bigger than or equal to 1, but how can we achieve that?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1244178/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1819113/42969

Comment: How much of calculus you are allowed to use?

Comment: @GuyFsone I would not call that a duplicate, as the asker of this question specifically needs a non-calculus solution. There are none of those for this problem on either of the links attached here.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen. I am not allowed to use any calculus. Only algebra. I've tried Bernoulli's inequality, but it only works for one exponent, as the other one is not in the right interval.

Comment: @fic19292 Do you know Taylor Series? There's a relatively nice proof of this using the taylor series expansion of $e^x$, if that's allowed. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @fic19292 But how we can even talk about exponential functions without calculus? You mean, you are not allowed to use derivatives, integrals, limits generally, right?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Not allowed, as is seen from comments.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Worth asking specifically.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen mope, not derivatives, limits, integrals, anything calculus-related. Also, the exponent rules are ones by elementary means, not functions. I am aware of the Taylor series proof, but I need to work only with algebra

Comment: @fic19292 With all those requirements, this is a nice task, will attempt again at a solution.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen that's why I asked this question, I can easily use a tiny amount of analysis and solve it, but algebraically without the use of calculus, I am not sure if I can do it.

Comment: @fic19292 What is the source of this problem? And what is your definition of $2^x$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I am not sure where I stumbled upon it, but I think it was another forum. The question was looking for a calculus solution, and I knew that solution, but I want a more elegant solution, one that, say, a gifted teenager can understand, maybe like an olympiad-type of solution, because this problem really reminds me of olympiad problems.
Edit: $2^x$ is 2 to the power of x, in the case that x is an integer, $2^x$ is $2*2*2*...*2*2$ x times, and for other real numbers x there exists a unique solution (e.g for $x={1\over 2}, 2^x$ is approximately $1.414...$)

Comment: A small observation: The given problem is equivalent to proving $$2^x + 2^{-x} \leq 2^{\sqrt{x^2+1}}, \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}. $$ This seems less daunting, but I am still not sure if we can come up with algebra-only proof.

Comment: related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858835/finding-the-maximum-and-minimum-values-of-fx-axa1-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set $$f(a)=2^a+2^{1\over a} = e^{a\ln2}+e^{\frac{1}{a}\ln2}\implies f'(a)=\ln2(2^a-\frac{2^{1\over a}}{a^2}) $$ 
it is not an obvious task to find the roots of $f'$ by hand 
despite that I opted for numerics. solving   $$f'(a)=\ln2(2^a-\frac{2^{1\over a}}{a^2}) =0~~~~~on~~~~ (-\infty, 0,)~~~ $$ gives  ([see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex-%5Cfrac%7B2%5E%7B1%2Fx%7D%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D%3D0))

$$\color{red}{a_0\approx -4,64886,~~~  ~~~~a_1=-1~~~~and ~~~~ a_2\approx -0,215106}$$

Moreover, on $(-\infty, a_0,)\cup (a_1,a_2)~~~~$ $f'(a)<0$ hence $f$ decreases therein

and on $ (a_0,a_1)\cup(a_2,0)~~~$ $f'(a)>0$ that is $f$ increases therein   [see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex-%5Cfrac%7B2%5E%7B1%2Fx%7D%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D%3D0)
also,  $$\lim_{a\to 0^-} f(a)= 1=\lim_{a\to -\infty, }f(a)$$

Therefore it follows that on $(-\infty, 0)$ the function  $f$ has unique maximum at $a_1= -1$. Whereas, $a_0$ and $a_2$ are minima of $f$.

that is $$f(a)=2^a+2^{1\over a}\le f(-1)=1~~~~\forall ~~a<0$$

Comment: Thank you, but I need a non-calculus solution :|

Comment: @fic19292 that was not part of the deal my friend

Comment: @Guy Fsone  Why $f$ has a maximum at $a=-1$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg i got your point it is not and obvious task to find by hand the roots of $f'$. despite that I opted for numerics and my statement still true see the update

Comment: It is just a question of how small amount of analysis is needed to solve this, but with none of analysis, I am not sure how, or can it be done.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, but I didn't expect such a tedious solution. It is a proof by cases, first you assume that x is the one whose absolute value is greater than or equal to 1, while it's reciprocal's absolute value is less than or equal to 1 OR VICE VERSA, then I look at two cases, the one where $x\le -2$, and the one where $-2<x\le -1$. Using algebraic manipulations and Bernoulli's inequality you get to the answer.
[image: Inequality proof]

Comment: solved it, why?

Comment: No, I wrote it down in powerpoint

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer your solution, only problem is I wanted an algebraic one. I got it but wasn't worth it.

Comment: Yesterday you said that it was not what you wanted ! good that you see how difficult it was

Comment: Well, I thought that the algebraic one would be more elegant, but it's a mess. So, yes I like it (yours) better now. Also, I marked it.

Comment: You might want to this also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858835/finding-the-maximum-and-minimum-values-of-fx-axa1-x

Comment: I looked at that. Should I favorite it or..?

Comment: yes i think it is more general although it not fully answer your question

Comment: It kind of does, the asker's first conjecture is basically my question, just a bit algebraically manipulated

Answer (score 0):

Let $2^a=x$.

Thus, $0<x<1$, $a=\log_2 x$ and we need to prove that
$$x+2^{\frac{1}{\log_2x}}\leq1$$ or
$$\frac{1}{\log_2x}\leq\log_2(1-x)$$ or
$$\log_2(1-x)\log_2x\leq1$$ or $f(x)\leq\ln^22,$
where $$f(x)=\ln(1-x)\ln{x}.$$
Indeed, $$f'(x)=-\frac{\ln{x}}{1-x}+\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}=\frac{(1-x)\ln(1-x)-x\ln{x}}{x(1-x)}.$$
We'll prove that $f'(x)>0$ for $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$ and $f'(x)<0$ for $\frac{1}{2}<x<1.$

Let $g(x)=(1-x)\ln(1-x)-x\ln{x}.$

Hence, $$g'(x)=-\ln(1-x)-1-\ln{x}-1=\ln\frac{1}{e^2x(1-x)}$$

$g'(x)=0$ gives $x^2-x+\frac{1}{e^2}=0$,

which gives that $g$ increases on $\left(0,\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{e^2}}}{2}\right]$ and on $\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{e^2}}}{2},1\right)$

and it gives that $g$ decreases on $\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{e^2}}}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{e^2}}}{2}\right]$.

Now, since $$g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1^-}g(x)=0,$$
we see that $f'(x)$ changes the sign in $x=\frac{1}{2}$ from $+$ to $-$, which   ends the proof.