# Prove $a^x+a^{1/x}\le 2a$ ($\frac{1}{2}\le a < 1$) for any $x\in (0,\infty)$

Tags: derivatives, inequality

> Prove $a^x+a^{1/x}\le 2a$ (with $\frac{1}{2}\le a < 1$) for any $x\in (0,\infty)$.

Is it true? I can't figure out how to prove it.
It may use the conclusion $\ln x+\frac{1-x}{x}\ge 0, \forall x\in (0,+\infty) $ as this question is followed.

---

**UPDATED:**

I have find a complicated method to prove it.
Let $f(x) = a^x+a^{1/x}-2a$, with $\frac{1}{2}\le a<1, x\in(0,\infty)$.

$\therefore f'(x)=a^{1/x}\ln \frac{1}{a}(\frac{1}{x^2}-a^{x-1/x})$

we have $a^{1/x}\ln\frac{1}{a}>0$, so we can only consider

$g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}-a^{x-1/x}, x>0, \frac{1}{2}\le a<1$

we can make the observation that $g(1)=0$, but **we are not sure if it has any other roots**. So we have to do some careful analysis.

If we keep taking derivative, we will get into endless trouble.

Note that $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}-a^{x-1/x}=a^{-2\log_a x}-a^{x-1/x}$

because $a<1$, so $a^x$ is decreasing, we can consider $h(x)=-2\log_a x-(x-\frac{1}{x})=-2\log_a x-x+\frac{1}{x},x>0,\frac{1}{2}\le a<1$

This is much easier. $h'(x)=-\dfrac{x^2+\dfrac{2}{\ln a}\cdot x+1}{x^2}$

because $\frac{1}{2}\le a<1$, so $\frac{2}{\ln a}\le -\frac{2}{\ln 2}\approx -2.9$. For the quadratic functions in the numerator, $\Delta >0$, there are two positive zeros $x_1,x_2$ and $0<x_1<1<x_2$, we have:

In $(0,x_1)$ and $(x_2,\infty)$，$h'(x)<0$, so $h(x)$ is decreasing.

In $(x_1, x_2)$, $h'(x)>0$, so $h(x)$ is increasing.

Note that $h(1)=0$, and when $x\to 0^+$, $h(x)\to +\infty$, when $x\to +\infty, h(x)\to -\infty$, therefore, the graph of $h(x)$ is illustrated as follows:

[[image: graph of <span class=]$h(x)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Ap7.png)

Therefore, there is three zeros for $h(x)$, i.e. $x_3, x_4=1, x_5$.

In $(0,x_3)$ and $(1,x_5)$, $h(x)>0$, so $g(x)<0$, so $f'(x)<0$, so $f(x)$ is decreasing.

In $(x_3,1)$ and $(x_5,+\infty)$, $h(x)<0$, so $g(x)>0$, so $f'(x)>0$, so $f(x)$ is increasing.

Note that $f(1)=0$, and when $x\to 0^+$, $f(x)\to 1-2a\le 0$; when $x\to +\infty$, $f(x)\to 1-2a\le 0$. The graph of $f(x)$ can be illustrated as follows:

[[image: graph of <span class=]$f(x)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djF08.png)

Now, we can surely say, the maximum of $f(x)$ is $f(1)=0$, which means $a^x+a^{1/x}\le 2a$, with $\frac{1}{2}\le a<1$, $\forall x\in(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the maximum and minimum values of $f(x)=a^x+a^{1/x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/858835) - Found by [Approach0](https://www.approach0.xyz).

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ Thanks, this question is closely related but the available answears were insufficient, but they really provide some clues.

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ: As far as I can see, the maximum for the case $1/2< a < 1$ is not determined in the answers to that thread (apart from a “if you plot the graph then you can see it”). My suggestion is *not* to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinR I agree. In that thread, the Conjecture 2 is not true. In fact, the situation for $0<a<\frac{1}{2}$ is different from that for $\frac{1}{2}\le a< 1$. The answears and discussions in that thread were insufficient. I have come up with a proof, but it is complicated. Maybe there is another more subtle approach?

Comment: @HansJ: Did you have a chance to check the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. Fix $a$ in the range $1/2 \le a < 1$. It suffices to prove
$$
a^x + a^{1/x}  \le 2a
$$
for $0 < x \le 1$, because the left-hand side is invariant under the substitution $x \leftrightarrow 1/x$. This inequality can be rearranged to
$$ 
g(x) := a^{-1/x} (2a - a^x) \ge 1 \,  .
$$
We have $g(1) = 1$, and we will now show that $g$ is *decreasing* on $(0, 1]$. The derivative is
$$
 g'(x) = \frac{a^{-1/x} \ln(a)}{x^2} \left( 2a - (x^2+1) a^x\right) \, .
$$
The first factor is negative, so we need to show that
$$
 2a - (x^2+1) a^x \ge 0 
$$
for $0 \le x \le 1$. It turns out to be convenient to set $y = 1-x$. With that substitution we need to show that
$$
 h(y) := 2a^y - 1- (1-y)^2 \ge 0
$$
for $0 \le y \le 1$. We have $h(0) = 0$ and $h(1) = 2a-1 \ge 0$, and the second derivative
$$
 h''(y) = 2 \left( \ln^2(a) \cdot a^y - 1\right)
$$
is negative. So $h$ is *concave* and therefore attains its minimum on the interval $[0, 1]$ at one of the boundary points.

We have thus shown that $h(y) \ge 0$, so that $g'(x) \le 0$, and therefore $g(x) \ge g(1) = 1$ for $0 < x \le 1$, and that completes the proof.

Comment: The initial part (defining the function $g$ in that way) is inspired by [this older answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/859903/42969) where the case $a=1/2$ is handled.